# hook_form_alter inside of hook_block_view - drupal 7

Tags: 7, forms, blocks

I have a form which I am calling inside of a custom block module. When the form is submitted it creates a session variable. I have hook_form_alter check to see if that variable is set; if it is, it will create a new form.

When I place the form inside of a block, it will not create the new form. Almost as if hook_form_alter is not being called.
Is there a better way to do this? Do I need to some how use hook_view_alter?

The form works fine outside of the block. It is only inside of the block I am having issues

Thanks in advance

Sample Code:

```
    function mymodule_block_info() {
        $blocks['mymodule-form-block'] = array(
            'info' => t('My Module Form Block'),
            'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
        );
        return $blocks;
    }

    /**
     * Implements hook_block_view().
     */
    function mymodule_block_view($delta = '') {
        $block = array();
        switch ($delta) {
            case 'mymodule-form-block':
                $block['subject'] = t('Subject');
                $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('mymodule_form');
                break;
        }
        return $block;
    }

    function mymodule_form() {
        $form['address'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t('Your Address'),
            '#size' => 60,
            '#maxlength' => 128,
            '#required' => TRUE,
        );
        $form['find_submit'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Value'),
            '#submit' => array('mymodule_form_submit'),
        );
        return $form;
    }

    function mymodule_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
        $_SESSION['readyToRender'] = $readyToRender;
    }
function contact_rep_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['readyToRender'])) {
        /* render some different form elements*/
         $form['submit'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Value'),
            '#submit' => array('mymodule_other_form_submit'),
        )


    unset($_SESSION['readyToRender']);
    }
}
    function mymodule_other_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
        /*Do things*/
    }
```

Comment: I' not sure if I'm understanding this correctly. Keep in mind that `hook_form_alter` is *NOT* invoked after submitting a form, but rather when it is built (before rendering).

Comment: That is correct. It is invoked while building, not after submitting.